# What SIP client for Windows does include g729 codec?

Tags: codec, sip

I'm looking for a, preferably free, multi-SIP client for Windows that does support g729 codec.

Comment: This works. And is free. (It's a bit tacky though)
http://braintel.net.pk/xpro-cnf.htm

And yes, Ekiga does not support g729
I doubt if any free software does, read more: http://turngeek.blogspot.com/2008/01/getting-g729-to-work-on-windows-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Per the comment below, g729 is now free. Definitely will open up more options for testing and VOIP solutions.

According to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.729#Licensing : "As of January 1, 2017 the patent terms of most Licensed Patents under the G.729 Consortium have expired, the remaining unexpired patents are usable on a royalty-free basis. Thus, G.729 can be used free-of-charge."

<s>Take a look at Bria. I use it at work and it is great. It supports g729.</s>

http://www.counterpath.com/bria.html

I also have tried Ekiga and it does not support g729, likely because the g729 license is not free.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.729#Licensing : "As of January 1, 2017 the patent terms of most Licensed Patents under the G.729 Consortium have expired, the remaining unexpired patents are usable on a royalty-free basis. Thus, G.729 can be used free-of-charge." So the above statement "... license is not free" is not correct as of 1/1/2017.

Answer (score 2):

[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) [claims](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Documentation#Technical_Specifications) to support G729. I'd start there.